# Reminders on android from within a custom app

Tags: android

Dear stackoverflowers,

I am currently working on a project which requires me to build an application which will have a schedule of events within it. I would like to allow users to add certain events to a "wish to attend list" which would essentially be a list of events the user needs to be reminded about. Now, I was wondering if it is at all possible to remind the user via either the default alarm or reminder (calendar) app, if not, what would you recommend?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You should use the notification framework for this.  That is where the Android user would expect these sort of messages to appear.

There are many examples of using the AlarmManager in concert with the NotificationManager package to accomplish exactly what you want.